# relative positions in android UI

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have a problem in designing user interface and layouts. i want that some views relates to others. for example a button related to a TextView and when i sat margin top, it calculates from that TextView not screen top. how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Relative Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html). They are the answer to your question. You can relate a view to another by setting it `toLeftOf`, `below`, `alignParentTop` or any other combination.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and Views will be positioned relative to other Views.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written it seems like you could group the TextView and Button into a container view, like a RelativeLayout, and fit them inside there with the appearance you would like.  Then you can set the margin of the Relative layout.

Edit: Clarity